# What is an In-page action? Please help me!

Tags: actions, page

I was wondering if you could help me out.

I am having difficulties with in- page actions.
What is an in-page action? Is it a session? A sequence of page views? Not needing to load a new url? A collection of session by one user?

What are some examples of in action? Is it goal conversion? Page view? Video starting?

Also is it the same as Call to action?

Comment: What is the context of where you're seeing "in-page actions"? Is it in an analytics platform?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without some more context, but in a general sense, I would assume an in-page action to be any action the user can perform on a given page, without navigating to a new page.

Sometimes this is clear cut, but it's less clear when dealing with interactions such as launching a modal window or similar actions on a complex SPA.

Exactly what could constitute an in-page action would depend on the specific page and exactly what your particular criteria are. Examples might include:

- Clicking on a button
- Entering data into a form
- Hovering over something without interacting
- Playing a video, stopping a video, rewinding a video (examples here to indicate that the level of granularity is dependent on use case)

There isn't really a canonical answer for what an in-page action is, they are often defined by your business and what it needs/wants to track in terms of actions.